# Where can I find entire Ramayana written by Valmiki without losing a single verse?

Tags: ramayana, translation-request, valmiki

I want to study entire Ramayana written by Valmiki because he is given not only the story but technology also present in it so please tell me where I can find entire Valmiki poems up to 22,000 poems please show me a way.

Comment: What are you talking about ,Valmiki Ramayana or something else? how can you say that there is technology mentioned in it, and even if there is technology hidden in valmiki ramayana how could you decipher it?

Comment: If you want till Yuddha Kanda alone valmikiramayan.net is an excellent site. If you want Uttara Kanda as well, then [Indian Scriptures](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/itihaas/ramayana/valmiki-ramayana-text-with-translation/vol-iv) gives the slokas with translation.

Comment: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/

Comment: I changed 220,000 to 22,000 in your Qn. Not sure if you really meant 220K verses, even the Mahabharata doesn't have so many verses.